# Hint for evaluating complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Question:

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int_C \frac{\mathrm dz}{z^2 +4}$$
>
> Along the line $x+y=1$ in the direction of increasing $x$.

There is no information about start point and end point.

How do i solve this?

If i want to parameterize this, i need some points for the lower and the upper bound in this integral. That's why i'm confused.

Please give me some hints, i don't need the "whole" answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just parameterize the path and do this directly. Recall $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) dt$. If you want the whole path, just let $a = -\infty$ and $b = \infty$

Comment: How do i get $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In this case, the line is infinitely long, there won't be a definite start or end point. If you parametrize by x or y, the bounds will include infinities.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So, i'm dealing with improper integral?

Comment: You could in theory choose to parametrize by some function that reaches infinity in finite time, but it is better in my opinion to just use infinite limits of integration. And yes, you are dealing with improper integral. In general complex analysis uses the improper Cauchy Principle Value integral for everything

Comment: Do lines have a start and end point?

Comment: @ElliotG Nah, this is what i'm thinking now. What is the bound btw? From negative infinity to infinity?

Comment: Yes. Not to be blunt but that question was answered multiple times.

Comment: Actually i got my answer, with some parameterization and u-substitution, i got this, please do some correction if there is a mistake. Thank all. $$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{u^2 +4}=\tan^{-1}(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @Masacroso i think it's just the definition of the contour integration and you can think about it as u-substitution (change variable) like in real integration. isn't it?

Comment: @user516076 I don't believe that is correct. You are integrating on a rotated line, not the real line.

Comment: @user516076 I think you got the result [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380759/complex-line-integrals-in-increasing-directions) but not sure if your method is correct or just coincidence